# SQL Filtering duplicate rows due to bad ETL

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates, filtering

The database is Postgres but any SQL logic should help.

I am retrieving the set of sales quotations that contain a given product within the bill of materials.  I'm doing that in two steps: step 1, retrieve all DISTINCT quote numbers which contain a given product (by product number).

The second step, retrieve the full quote, with all products listed for each unique quote number.

So far, so good.  Now the tough bit.  Some rows are duplicates, some are not.  Those that are duplicates (quote number & quote version & line number) might or might not have maintenance on them.  I want to pick the row that has maintenance greater than 0.  The duplicate rows I want to exclude are those that have a 0 maintenance.  The problem is that some rows, which have no duplicates, have 0 maintenance, so I can't just filter on maintenance.

To make this exciting, the database holds quotes over 20+ years.  And the data scientists guys have just admitted that *maybe* the ETL process has some bugs...

```
--- step 0
--- cleanup the workspace
SET CLIENT_ENCODING TO 'UTF8';
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS product_quotes;

--- step 1
--- get list of Product Quotes
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE product_quotes AS (
   SELECT DISTINCT master_quote_number
   FROM w_quote_line_d

   WHERE item_number IN ( << model numbers >> )
);

--- step 2
--- Now join on that list
SELECT 
d.quote_line_number,
d.item_number,
d.item_description,
d.item_quantity,
d.unit_of_measure,
f.ref_list_price_amount,
f.quote_amount_entered,
f.negtd_discount,
--- need to calculate discount rate based on list price and negtd discount (%)
CASE
    WHEN ref_list_price_amount > 0 
        THEN 100 - (ref_list_price_amount + negtd_discount) / ref_list_price_amount *100
    ELSE 0
END AS discount_percent,

f.warranty_months,
f.master_quote_number,
f.quote_version_number,
f.maintenance_months,
f.territory_wid,
f.district_wid,
f.sales_rep_wid,
f.sales_organization_wid,
f.install_at_customer_wid,
f.ship_to_customer_wid,
f.bill_to_customer_wid,
f.sold_to_customer_wid,
d.net_value,
d.deal_score,
f.transaction_date,
f.reporting_date

FROM w_quote_line_d d
INNER JOIN product_quotes pq ON (pq.master_quote_number = d.master_quote_number)

INNER JOIN w_quote_f f ON 
    (f.quote_line_number = d.quote_line_number 
    AND f.master_quote_number = d.master_quote_number 
    AND f.quote_version_number = d.quote_version_number)

WHERE d.net_value >= 0 AND item_quantity > 0
ORDER BY f.master_quote_number, f.quote_version_number, d.quote_line_number
```

**The logic to filter the duplicate rows is like this:** 
For each master_quote_number / version_number pair, check to see if there are duplicate line numbers.  If so, pick the one with maintenance > 0.

Even in a CASE statement, I'm not sure how to write that.

Thoughts?  The database is Postgres but any SQL logic should help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will want to use [Window Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html). They are, in a word, awesome.

Here is a query that would "dedupe" based on your criteria:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        * -- simplifying here to show the important parts
        ,row_number() over (
            partition by master_quote_number, version_number
            order by maintenance desc) as seqnum
    from w_quote_line_d d
    inner join product_quotes pq 
    on (pq.master_quote_number = d.master_quote_number)
    inner join w_quote_f f 
    on (f.quote_line_number = d.quote_line_number
      and f.master_quote_number = d.master_quote_number 
      and f.quote_version_number = d.quote_version_number)
) x
where seqnum = 1
```

The use of `row_number()` and the chosen `partition by` and `order by` criteria guarantee that only ONE row for each combination of quote_number/version_number will get the value of 1, and it will be the one with the *highest* value in maintenance (if your colleagues are right, there would only be one with a value > 0 anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like...

```
select
    *
from
    w_quote_line_d d
    inner join
        (
            select
                ...
                ,max(maintenance)
            from
                w_quote_line_d
            group by
                ...
        ) d1
   on 
       d1.id = d.id
       and d1.maintenance = d.maintenance;
```

Am I understanding your problem correctly?

**Edit:** Forgot the group by!

Comment: This will work, but a self-join is almost always more expensive than the equivalent query using window functions

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure, but maybe you could `Group By` all other columns and use `MAX(Maintenance)` to get only the greatest.

What do you think?